# How to assign default value for a color?

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to assign a default color `Color(0xFF1D1E33)` to the widget if no value is assigned where the widget is used

```
class ReusableContainer extends StatelessWidget {
  Color colour;
  ReusableContainer({this.colour});
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      margin: EdgeInsets.all(15),
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
        color: colour,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

```
ReusableContainer(colour: Color(0xFFF48024)), //assigned value here
.........
.........
ReusableContainer()  //default value here
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change your constructor from:

```
ReusableContainer({this.colour});
```

to

```
ReusableContainer({this.colour = const Color(0xFF1D1E33)});
```

Answer (score 3):

You can either use default value of named parameter (it will be nullable) or null-aware operator to set a property (it won't be nullable).

```dart
class ReusableContainer extends StatelessWidget {
  Color colour;
  ReusableContainer({this.colour = const Color(0xFF1D1E33)});

  ...
```

or

```dart
class ReusableContainer {
  Color colour;
  ReusableContainer({Color colour}) : colour = colour ?? const Color(0xFF1D1E33);

  ...
}
```

Comment: @Akhil np, I've updated the answer with one more approach.

Comment: That's great, Thanks again =D